# View all jobs by Company X gives me other companies

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs

The company filter in the keywords doesn't work right.  It uses some strange fuzzy logic to include companies you aren't referring to.

[image]

When applying a filter it should use an exact match on the company name.

Comment: It's an issue with our ElasticSearch implementation that I've been told isn't easy to fix. I don't have a specific answer as to when or if it's going to be fixed.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for the report. This is now fixed and pushed to prod!

Comment: Thanks Dean this wasn't working this morning.  Is this due to elastic search or something else, just curious

Comment: Yup, we were doing a match query over the company name, it should have been a match_phrase query instead (so it respects ordering of the words).